# Search Kit fatal error

Tags: searchkit

WP 5.7.8 PHP 8.0.26 civi 5.51.1 Search kit 5.51.1

Any search - I tested with simple contact = type individual, reports no result. Civi screen stays the same ie no error message just no result.

Unfortunately I can't upgrade due to Kinsta issues (see other thread [ServiceNotFoundException for "spec_gatherer" on CiviCRM 5.55+ when hosting with Kinsta](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/43412/servicenotfoundexception-for-spec-gatherer-on-civicrm-5-55-when-hosting-with) )

Error 1=

```
2023/03/27 05:10:50 [error] 114740#114740: *646 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
"PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: 
Civi\Api4\Action\SearchDisplay\Run::processResult(): Argument #1 ($result) 
must be of type Civi\Api4\Result\SearchDisplayRunResult, 
Civi\Api4\Generic\Result given, 
called in /www/invasives_235/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Api4/Action/SearchDisplay/AbstractRunAction.php on line 114 
and defined in /www/invasives_235/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Api4/Action/SearchDisplay/Run.php:37
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /www/####/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/search_kit/Civi/Api4/Action/SearchDisplay/AbstractRunAction.php(114): 
Civi\Api4\Action\SearchDisplay\Run->processResult(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#1 /www/####/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(69): 
Civi\Api4\Action\SearchDisplay\AbstractRunAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#2 /www/#####/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Ker" while reading response header from upstream, client: 125.168.64.134, server: env-#####-pushciviug.kinsta.cloud, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php8.0-fpm-#####.sock:", host: "env-###-pushciviug.kinsta.cloud:26165", referrer: "https://env-#####-pushciviug.kinsta.cloud/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsearch"
```

and browser errors are:

```
jquery.min.js:4          POST https://env-#####-pushciviug.kinsta.cloud/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Fapi4 500
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ crm.ajax.js?r=Pt4f9en_AU:85
CRM.api4 @ crm.ajax.js?r=Pt4f9en_AU:72
crmApi4 @ angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:17
runSearch @ angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3909
(anonymous) @ angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3819
$eval @ angular.js:19523
$apply @ angular.js:19622
(anonymous) @ angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3818
e @ lodash.min.js:40
setTimeout (async)
o @ lodash.min.js:41
onClickSearchButton @ angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3895
fn @ VM7696:4
e @ angular.js:29123
$eval @ angular.js:19523
$apply @ angular.js:19622
(anonymous) @ angular.js:29127
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
angular.js:15697 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'debug')
    at controller.<anonymous> (angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3163:71)
    at angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3936:22
    at qt (lodash.min.js:9:507)
    at Function.Re (lodash.min.js:37:336)
    at angular-modules.af5fd05bc138b0651c13190765a8f2df.js:3935:13
    at angular.js:18075:37
    at m.$digest (angular.js:19242:15)
    at angular.js:19562:15
    at Yg.completeTask (angular.js:21403:7)
    at angular.js:6879:7 'Possibly unhandled rejection: {}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Kinsta hosting caching was the issue. Search Kit worked once they enabled opcache.save_comments in the Nginx server cache